# Retrieve Django rest framework related fields

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Using the [django-rest-framework](http://django-rest-framework.org/) is it possible to retrieve content from a related field. So for example I want to create a genre list which contains all projects within it. This is what I have but I keep on getting the error:

> 'Genre' object has no attribute 'project_set'

models.py

```
class Genre(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True)

class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    genres = models.ManyToManyField(Genre, related_name='genres')
```

serializers.py

```
class GenreSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):    
    project_set = serializers.ManyRelatedField()

    class Meta:
        model = Genre
        fields = ('name', 'project_set')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The related name you're using on the `Project` class is badly named.  That related name is how you access the set of projects related to a given genre instance.  So you should be using something like `related_name='projects'`.  (As it is you've got it the wrong way around.)

Then make sure that your serializer class matches up with the related name you're using, so in both places `project_set` should then instead be `projects`.

(Alternatively you could just remove the `related_name='genres'` entirely and everything will work as you were expecting, as the default related_name will be `'project_set'`.)